# log4j with spring create empty file

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, log4j

I want to use log4j 1.2.9 with spring 4.0.1 and JBOSS 7.1 but every time i get log information on console but the file is created and empty ...

log4j.properties

```
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=C:\\log\\loggingFile.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n


log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file, stdout
```

web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/log4j.properties</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Simple test Controller

```
import org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
@ManagedBean(name="MyController")
public class MyController {
    static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyController.class);
    public String test() {
    BasicConfigurator.configure();  
    logger.debug(LoginController.class);  
    logger.info("Info.. ");  
    logger.error("Error..");  
    logger.fatal("Fatal");   
      return null;
  }}
```

Comment: I am not sure about the Spring config listener but the log4j system property to define the config file resource ist `log4j.configuration` and not `log4jConfigLocation` (https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html#defaultInit)

Comment: when i change it to log4j.configuration the file is not created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution was to add jboss-deployment-structure.xml in /WEB-INF to exclude org.apache.log4j

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        dependencies -->
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Answer (score 0):

As your configurations look fine to me, I believe you have an extra copy of the `log4j.jar` in your `webapp`.

Moreover, why don't you use the logging `subsystem` present in `JBoss AS 7.x`? By this subsystem, you can have centralized configuration for all you want to achieve. It will be easier to maintain as well.

For this, just remove `log4j.properties` and import `log4j`/`slf4j` via dependencies and make sure you don't pack your own `log4j`/`slf4j` jars in your `webapp`.

Check out [Logging Configuration](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Logging+Configuration) for JBoss.

Shishir

Comment: thx I know i can use that but im asked  to use my own log4j configuration is there any other way ?